# Is there an alternative to changed touches for safari based browsers?

Tags: javascript, mobile, dom-events, touch

I have some touch events in my javascript code that use `event.changedTouches` but the browser on IOS that are based off of safari don't support it. Does anybody have an alternative thanks - Dave.

I've tried event.preventOthers and I already have event.preventDefaults. I just want to be able to get the index's of the fingers that have change in that event.